# Task gets completed by system in CRM 13

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

The scenario is a 'Task' gets created and marked as completed by one CRM user.
When I open that CRM form(new form for CRM13), in 'Activities' it shows 'last updated' field in bottom of each activities.

So, below that Task, it shows that 'Completed by System'.

[image: System]

In audit history I can see that 'Completed by CRM User' 
but on the form it shows 'Completed by System'. How can this possible.

Does anybody have any idea regarding this? please help.
Any idea would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you already ruled out [Script / Plugin / Process / External code] misbehavior ?

Comment: No, I have not done any customization on these part.

Answer (score 0):

Completed by System refers to the Workflow Owner who created the workflow
Completed by user refers to the User who caused the workflow to be triggered